# multiple iteration of the same list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, shapely

I have one list of data as follows:

```
from shapely.geometry import box

data = [box(1,2,3,4), box(4,5,6,7), box(1,2,3,4)]
sublists = [A,B,C]
```

The list 'data' has following sub-lists:

```
A = box(1,2,3,4)
B = box(4,5,6,7)
C = box(1,2,3,4)
```

I have to check if sub-lists intersect. If intersect they should put in one tuple; and if not intersect should put in different tuple. The expected result is:

```
result = [(A,C), (B)]
```

How to do it?

I tried it as:

```
results = []
for p,c in zip(data,sub_lists):
    for x in data:
        if p.intersects(x): ##.intersects return true if they overlap else false
            results.append(c)
print results
```

Comment: For those of us who haven't worked with `shapely`, what can be done with the object that `box()` returns?  Is this a question about comparing/iterating over Python lists, or about using `shapely`.  And how does 'numpy' enter the equation?

Comment: @hpaulj its about python lists. But shapely is used to test intersect. the box() return shapely polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without downloading `shapely`, I think what you want to do with lists can be replicated with strings (or integers):

```
In [221]: data=['one','two','three']    
In [222]: data1=['one','four','two']

In [223]: results=[[],[]]
In [224]: for i in data1:
    if i in data:
        results[0].append(i)
    else:
        results[1].append(i)
   .....:         

In [225]: results
Out[225]: [['one', 'two'], ['four']]
```

Replace the `i in data` with your `intersects` tests.  The first sublist of `results` contains the elements of `data1` for which the test is true.  The second sublist contains the elements where it is false.

Your question is a little confusing in that `data` and `sublists` appear to contain the same elements.  So maybe you aren't testing whether `A` is in `data` (or intersect with an element of `data`), but whether `A` intersects with an other element of `[A,B,C]`, etc.

In any case, the key to collecting the results is to have two (or more) slots in `results`, where you can put `i` depending on the test.  `results` could also be a dictionary, or could be two different variables. e.g. `results={'found':[],'lost':[]}`.

Do we need to work more on the test?

```
A 'intersects with' any of [B,C]
B 'intersects with' any of [A,C]
C 'intersects with' any of [A,B]
```